# Angular 2: Unable to include component into another

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

There are quite a few posts in StackOverflow that provide better details than the Angular 2 doc on how to include a custom component inside another custom component.

However, even if I follow those instructions (ensure the injected component is in the `declarations` block of the module definition, and also ensure the injected component is in the `directives` block of the component definition), it still throws an error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'test' is not a known element:
1. If 'test' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'test' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
</footer>

[ERROR ->]<test></test>
```

You can take a look at the [Github repo](https://github.com/jansensan/a11y-simulated-dialog-angular/tree/master/src/scripts/components/index-page-content). I started [a branch](https://github.com/jansensan/a11y-simulated-dialog-angular/tree/1-ensure-nested-components-work) where I try and figure it out.

What could I have forgotten? Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

They are in different modules.
Put them into one module and rebuild project.

Comment: I specifically want them to be separate modules, for reuse and separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Test Component should be used as a shared module in this case, where as you are trying to use it like a feature module as both these modules are independent Angular is not able to find the module.

Either put both the components in a same module or use the test Component as a shared module.

Comment: Yes, I guess it's indeed a shared module that I am trying to build. However, I can't figure out what import/injection/declarations etc. is required for that kind of stuff. Documentation is all across the board and not compartimentalized in explaining one thing at a time. In this case, I would put the `TestModule`in the `imports` block of the module using the injected one, but that still fails.

Comment: You need to create a new class as shared module and then in that class using the export tag list all the components you want to be used as shared resource  and then use the shared module in the feature module imports

Comment: I do have the `TestModule`, but it doesn't matter if I put that in the `imports` block, I still get an error.